# "And yet we're meant to be educating them for it." What does this mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, speech

I was watching a TED video and didn’t get a few of the sentences. I hope someone can explain them to me.

> So I have a big interest in education, and I think we all do. We have a huge vested interest in it, partly because it's education that's meant to take us into this future that we can't grasp. If you think of it, children starting school this year will be retiring in 2065. Nobody has a clue, despite all the expertise that's been on parade for the past four days, what the world will look like in five years' time. **And yet we're meant to be educating them for it.** So the unpredictability, I think, is extraordinary.

What does "And yet we're meant to be educating them for it" mean?

Comment: What, specifically, do you not understand?  It's actually fairly clearly written, for an educator.

Comment: And yet we're meant to be educating them for it.                                  What does that sentence mean. ?

Comment: **"meant"** in the sentence is used to say what educators/teachers are supposed to teach, the **purpose** or goal of education is to prepare/educate/train students  for the big bad world see: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meant. Or were you confused by the term *yet*?

Comment: If you could say what you believe the sentence means, then you stand a very good chance of reopening your question. The question is closed not because users don't like it, but because native speakers can't understand why you find it particularly difficult.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  no worries

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not educator I'm student

Comment: @Mari-LouA no it is already clear to me. Thank you. .you are very helpful

Comment: My pleasure, but I wondering why you asked the same question twice.

Comment: @VasifBakuAzerbaijan - I wasn't saying you were the educator, I was referring to the person speaking.

Comment: The thing is not really clearly worded, but it's raising a point about education today.  100 years ago we all new that people needed to learn "the three Rs" to have a good, solid basic education.  Maybe 25% of students went on and learned a little more to complete high school, and 5% went on to earn a college degree, but even the properties of a good college education were well known and agreed on.  These days it's not clear, especially in technical fields, what knowledge will be useful in 10 years, much less after a lifetime.  So "knowledge" is less important than learning and coping skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, there are two teams in the teaching profession -- the educators and the educationists.  Educators are teachers, and they understand that their duty is to teach students to think.  Educationists are apparatchiks, and for them the goal of education is to provide students with skills immediately applicable for dealing with those students' post-graduate lives, particularly their working lives.  You are quoting an educationist, and his worry is that he can't see a way to impart skills for a work life, the details of which he can't predict.  In other words, his students may work for the next fifty years, but it's impossible to predict what the workplace will be like in as little as five years, and if the unpredictability is so great, how can educationists design an appropriate curriculum?

Comment: I wouldn't read it exactly that way.  Even the old 3-R educators have no idea if even addition will be relevant in 20 years.

Comment: @HotLicks Educators don't teach mathematics because their students might have to add columns of numbers in their upcoming jobs.   That's what educationists worry about.  Maybe by graduation no jobs will require doing manual sums, but if we don't know what futuristic calculators will look like or whether they'll even be necessary, what's to be taught?

Comment: What's to be taught?  How to learn.  And how to separate prescriptive nonsense from real life wisdom.

Comment: @HotLicks As should be clear from my answer, that's an educator's response.  An educator will take as an axiom that the ability to learn and the ability to separate that you mention will be valuable to students now, five years from now, and fifty years from now when he's dead, independent of what the world looks likes.  An educationist reply is "What will useful on the job."  But it's hard to predict what things will look like "on the job", thus the OP's cite about the problem of "unpredictability".

Comment: Because I didn't get you at first